# difference between have been and had been

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

My friend just answered to one of my important questions. Now how should I reply to him?

> 1.Oh! That question **had been on my mind** for a long time, finally, I got my answer. *( Oh! I **had that question on my mind** for a long time, finally, I got my answer)*

or

> 2. Oh! That question **has been on my mind** for a long time, finally, I got an answer. *( Oh! I **have that question on my mind** for a long time, finally, I got my answer)*

Basically, I am confused with had and have. Since that question is not anymore on my mind after having got an answer, which one of the above two sentences should be used?